# one or more valid Kubernetes manifests are required to run skaffold

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

When I run `skaffold init` in my app directory it shows me:

```
one or more valid Kubernetes manifests are required to run skaffold
```

The content of the directory:

[image]

Do I have to provide Kubernetes manifests file with for example Pod, Service, etc?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you need Kubernetes manifests in the same project. Typically a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)-manifest and perhaps Service and Ingress as well if you want.

A Deployment-manifest can be generated with (using `>` to direct output to a file):

```
kubectl create deployment my-app --image=my-image --dry-run -o yaml > deployment.yaml
```

Note: There is a alpha feature flag [--generate-manifests](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/init/#--generate-manifests-flag) that might do this for you.

E.g. with

```
skaffold init --generate-manifests
```